# Reversing elements html order with z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a `div` with a nested `div` inside, and I want to reverse their order of display **without** changing the HTML structure.

```
<div class="round">
    <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

At first I gave the inner div a `z-index` of `-1` and it worked, but I need it to be over `0` so I gave it a `z-index` of `1` and the parent div `2`. The problem is that no matter the value of the z-index I give the parent, whenever he has that attribute, the order goes back to normal.

Both divs have `position` other than `static` so `z-index` should effect them.

```
.round {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
 /* z-index: 1; adding this reverses the order back to normal */
}

.progress {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #6eb348;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -4px;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    right: -4px;
    z-index: -1; /* I need this to be higher then 0 */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/JeVA9/4/

Comment: When you set `z-index` on an element, you create a new stacking context, such that all children of that element are "applied" to the document in general using the container's `z-index`.

Comment: Can't you change the css style, so the .round div would be the green larger, and the .progress would be the yellow smaller?

Comment: Are you sure you need .progress z-index to be higher than 0 ? You don't explain why, and I think that it is your only posibility

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check a small change in both HTML and CSS Code. Maybe this can help.....

```
<div>
    <div class="round"></div>
    <div class="progress"></div>
</div>


.round {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
   z-index: 2;  
}

.progress {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #6eb348;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 3px;
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 3px;
    right: -4px;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

Here according to me you've to adjust top, bottom, left and right area according to your requirement in .progress class. But this will help.....